# Returning a variable and a function (recursion)

Tags: javascript, recursion

When running the following script, the return value at the end of the function is 3.

```js
function testFunction(num) {
  
  console.log(num);
  
  if (num == 0) {
    return num;
  }
  
  return num - testFunction(num - 1);
}

console.log("Final result is: " + testFunction(5));
```

If the return statement was switched from

```
return num - testFunction(num - 1);
```

to

```
return num + testfunction(num - 1);
```

the return value at the end is 15 (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0).

How does the original return statement end up with 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's trace out the recursion when `return num - testFunction(num - 1);`

```
tf(5) = 5 - tf(4)  
tf(4) = 4 - tf(3)  
tf(3) = 3 - tf(2)  
tf(2) = 2 - tf(1)  
tf(1) = 1 - tf(0)  
tf(0) = 0 **Base Case**
```

Now, let's unfurl the recursion once we hit our base case of tf(0) = 0:

```
tf(0) = 0  
tf(1) = 1 - 0 = 1  
tf(2) = 2 - 1 = 1  
tf(3) = 3 - 1 = 2  
tf(4) = 4 - 2 = 2  
tf(5) = 5 - 2 = 3
```

So, the function ultimately returns 3

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug (in this case, to understand what is happening) is to print every step of recursion;

```js
function testFunction(num) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return num;
  }
  
  const nextResult = testFunction(num - 1)
  console.log(`f(${num}) = ${num} - ${nextResult} = ${num - nextResult}`)
  return num - nextResult;
}

console.log("Final result is: " + testFunction(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `testFunction(5)` returns `5 - testFunction(4)`, and `testFunction(4)` returns `2`.

`5 - 2` is `3`, so `testFunction(5)` returns `3`.